# Create a topography map base in QGIS

Tags: qgis, topography

I am building an interactive web bike map and I would like three baselayers. Currently, I have an OpenStreetMap layer and I would like to add a topography layer. I am aiming for something shown on this website: http://www.vttrack.fr/ The three baselayers I am aiming to get are OpenStreetMap (I have this), topography map, and IGN map.

My coordinate reference system is EPSG:3857

Can I get the topography data from the OpenStreetMap?

My map can be found here: https://revyrob.github.io/bikeSerChe/map2.html

I had made a topography map using Mapbox but when I created the html with qgis2web the map did not work as a baselayer. By creating my own map on QGIS I don't have to worry about fees incurred with Mapbox and I am also excited to learn.

Comment: Have you seen the OSM 'Cycle Map' basemap? I think it might be a good solution for what you're after: https://www.opencyclemap.org/?zoom=10&lat=39.60973&lon=-105.41374&layers=B0000 and it can be used as a tile layer in a web map

Answer (score 3):

For QGIS I was able to add the plugin 'quickmapservices' which gives me access to different basemaps: OSM, Nasa, etc.  I was able to add the OSM Cyclemap to the base layer using the 'quickmapservice' plugin. I then needed an account for Thunderforest to access the API for OSM Cyclemap.  Once I created an account I added a 'new connection' to the XYZ tile and the URL provided by Thunderforest with my API key.